# Loading data as .js file vs. loading as JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, performance

I couldn't find any existing page on this, perhaps I'm not using the right search keywords...

Say I'm  implementing a simple JavaScript search engine for my static site, and my searchable contents (a large file) are stored in a file and loaded during initial page load.

Now I can load the content file in two ways:

**1.** The contents are stored in a Javascript variable in a `search_content.js` file:

```
// Large js file
var content = {"pages": [ {"page": "..."}, {...}, ... ]};
```

In my HTML I load it using:

```
<script src="search_content.js"></script>
```

And my search engine would just access the `content` variable.

**2.** Keep the searchable content in a JSON file `search_content.json`:

```
// Large json file
{"pages": [ {"page": "..."}, { ... } ... ]}
```

And load the file in my search library after page load:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url_to_my_json_file,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Method 1 can be run without a web server, but aside from that, what are the differences, benefits/drawbacks for each method? Are they the same performance-wise?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the latter can be better when there is a noticable delay in the initial rendering of the page, as this can be considered as a way of lazy loading.

Performance-wise the first one would be most likely more efficient, however the *perceived performance* could be a more important factor here.

One other thing comes to my mind, the second way does not pollute the global scope, this could be an advantage.

Comment: In method 1, if I put the <script> tag at the bottom of my page, would that also achieve the same effect of loading after the page finishes rendering?

Comment: Yes, provided that you are not trying to actually use the data before inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading *data*, it seems right to use a *data* format, not code. By using JSON instead of JS code you're limiting the scope of possible failures. Even if the data fails to parse, the page itself won't be affected, only the search will not work. So the JSON approach is safer.

Since the data is probably not needed to display the initial page, it seems right to load it *asynchronously*, so that it doesn't delay the loading of the page. The script tag will defer the loading of your page unless you put it at the end of your HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You might wanna take a look at this post [Using JSON to Exchange Data](http://betterexplained.com/articles/using-json-to-exchange-data/)

Comment: The linked post seems useful, however a link-only answer is less so :) Please try to collect the most important points here, or post this as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link! One of my problem while looking into this was finding relevant articles on this, that article should serve as a good starting point :)

Comment: @slsdo  I am interested to find the answer to your question. Did you find the relevant part in the article? I couldn't. Honestly people who'd find this question interesting would already be well versed with what JSON is and how to create a JSobject etc, something the the article spends a lot of time explaining. Care to tl;dr ? thanks

Comment: @anu after reading that article I agree with you that it doesn't really answer my particular question (performance, pro/con, of each method etc.), if I do find anything in the future I'll definitely come back and update my post!